# Php treating greater-than as end script

Tags: php, html, apache

recently after testing my sql query script I came across a problem. The greater than sign in my if statement ended the php and then output the rest of the code as html.

Here is my code. (It's in "poll.html", an html file with php code in it)

```
<div class="pollcont">
<?php

$pollrow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Activepoll` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");

$rows = mysql_num_rows($pollrow);


if($rows > 0){ Do this stuff }; ?> </div>
```

Instead of finishing the if statement,  `0){ Do this stuff }; ?`> is output into the browser.

Why is this happening and how can I change this so the script will work?

Comment: this is a `yourfile.php` right?

Comment: what is " Do this stuff" ?

Comment: It's an html file, with php code in it. Should it be a php file that echos the html content?

Comment: "Do this stuff" is just a bunch of assigned variables from the sql call, and then an echoing of the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file must have the extension ".php".

What your seeing is your browser treating the PHP open tag "<" to the greater than sign ">" as an HTML element and simply hiding that source code. Its not processing anything while its an html file.

Comment: Thanks! So to achieve the same effect I should make this a php file and echo the html elements from that?

Comment: Not necessary. ".php" files will render HTML external to <?php ?> tags just like normal HTML. That is one of the major benefits of using PHP at all.

Simply change the file to poll.php and open it in your browser ;)

Comment: Or you can configure your webserver to process .html files with PHP. This is another advantage of PHP -- if the file doesn't contain `<?php`, it will just be rendered as is.